# Design of an MVVM Application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, system-design

I am here very skeptical about the design of my application.....

Here is the Diagram for My application

[image: Diagram of my Application]

is this right ?? ot i need to change something...

I'll Elaborate the Diagram.... :

Common Library : It Contains classes ErrorCodes,Utility Classes etc
Logger : Logging Framework
Exception Handling : Framework for handling exceptions

View: Contains : All the Different XAML for Views like UserControls,Windows,Popups

ViewModel : Contains ViewModels for the Differents Views.

Model : Contains holds the Different layers like ... Business Layer, Data Access layer etc

Entity layer : Contains the Entity Objects like Employee, Company etc...

File box : Its specify Reading/Writing from a file/ Database ....

Comment: This may be the most vague question I've ever seen.  What does the application do?  What is a "TreeNode"?  What does the "File" box mean?  Does "Common Library" mean a common C# project or the BCL?  These are all obvious questions a person would need to know to figure out how to come close to answering this.

Comment: Its just a System Design... View,Models,ViewModels are Symbolic.. treat them as you like

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers I have added the description as you asked... If you find something still missing please let me know ill try to post that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to tell what you're trying to do with your question, but in my opinion MVVM layers should look like this:

- **Model**: Raw data and raw-data validation. Maybe an `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well, but nothing else
- **ViewModel**: Business Logic, data access, advanced validation based on business rules, etc
- **Views**: Pretty UI layer that allows users to interact with the ViewModels. Nothing else.

For example, a Model might have a `File` property, but it should not be responsible for showing the file dialog, saving the file to the database, or verifying that the file has a .pdf extension. That sort of stuff is the ViewModel's job.

**Edit**

I see the update you made to your question. It's an OK start, but here's the issues I have with it:

- Your models should be raw data objects. They should not contain anything more advanced than something like validating the length of a property.
- I honestly would not recommend separating the Views, Models, and ViewModels into 3 separate layers. I did that once and it turned out to be a maintenance nightmare. Now I put all related objects together. For example I'd put `FileModel`, `FileViewModel`, and `FileView` together, and `SearchModel`,`SearchViewModel`, and `SearchView` together
- I would create a Data Access Layer which would be responsible for doing all read/writing data to/from the database (I suppose this could be your "Entity Layer").
- For small projects, I tend to use my Entity Objects as my Models, so the Models become part of my DAL layer, although I know this is not recommended.
- Don't forget, with MVVM your ViewModels are your application, not your Views. The View should reflect what's in the ViewModel, and not vice versa.

Comment: Good explanation of MVVM, this is pretty much how I implement my own MVVM projects

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for helping, I would try to correct my Design as Explained... but still one doubt i have... Where should my Business Layer be ... below ViewModel and Above Model ???

Comment: @adcool2007 Your business layer should be your ViewModels. For example, your FileViewModel should be in charge of calling the DAL to get or save data, for showing dialog boxes or opening files, and handling any business logic.

Comment: @Rachel Thanks ill make the necessay changes... :)